# How to define a recurrence relation in Maple?

Tags: maple, computer-algebra-systems

I'm new with Maple and want to define a recurrence relation. I want to 1) have Maple solve it to the explicit formula 2)have Maple output a few evaluations of it for various values of `n`

For example if I have $a_n=2a_{n-1}+3a_{n-2}$ with $a_0=1$ and $a_1=2$ how would I use Maple to solve for an explicit formula and output the evaluated $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$?

In terms of Maple commands, do I want to define a function or does a recurrence sequence have it's on "type"? I know I want to use `rsolve` but I haven't got the commands right. Could someone please give me an example?

EDIT: the given solutions don't seem to work if you do a second recurrence realtion, that is having $a(n)$ equal to something else and try solving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the **makeproc** option to **rsolve**.

`A:= rsolve({a(n)=2*a(n-1)+3*a(n-2), a(0)=1, a(1)=2}, a(n), makeproc):`

`A(n);`

```
                     1     n   3  n
                     - (-1)  + - 3 
                     4         4
```

`'A(n)' $ n= 1..4;`

```
                      2, 7, 20, 61
```

Comment: In `A:= rsolve({a(n)=2*a(n-1)+3*a(n-2), a(0)=1, a(1)=2}, a(n), makeproc):` why do you have `:` instead of `;` at the end? Also what difference does it make that the second argument is `a(n)` instead of just `a`?

Comment: The colon at the end of a command is to suppress the printed output of that command. Using `a` or `a(n)` as the second argument makes no difference as far as I can tell. I was not aware that it could be abbreviated to `a`.

Comment: This only works the first time. See edit to question.

Comment: You've probably made an assignment to one of the variables involved in the problem. I can't diagnose further without seeing your code.

Comment: Is it Maple able to solve this recurrence https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140338/how-to-solve-this-multivariate-recurrence-with-mathematica not solved by Mathematica?

Comment: Maple cannot solve recurrences with more than one independent variable.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define the recurrence relation, for example:

> eqn1 $:=a(n) = 2*a(n-1) + 3*a(n-2);$

Then you have to give the initial values:

> init1 $:=a(0)=1,a(1)=2;$

Then use *rsolve* to solve it for $a$:

> soln1[n]:=rsolve({eqn1,init1},a);

If you want to evaluate the solution for $n = 1,2,3,4$, then just write (for example, $n=4$)

> eval(soln1[n], $n=4$);

Here is a [reference sheet](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~peterseb/mth355/docs/355f2001_recur.pdf) if you have further questions. Hope, that helped.

Comment: You're missing a big part of what I was trying to ask. How can I plug in just one number, for example how would I do a(3)? I already red the link and I don't think it's right because the defines an "equation" and in Maple you can't plug values into an equation, only "functions". But what do I know I'm just learning.

Comment: @Celeritas Sorry, I assumed that you know how to evaluate a function in Maple ;-) Edited my post.

Comment: This only works the first time. See edit to question.

Comment: @Celeritas My answer is right to your question. If you extend the question, my answer is still right. ;-) Anynway, why don't you just rename the second *a(n)* to *b(n)* or rename the eqn1 to eqn2 and so on?

Comment: So I need to rename both $eqn1$ and $a(n)$? The reason I'm suppressed is because I didn't realize we were actually defining $a(n)$ permanently since we didn't use the $:=$ operator.

Comment: If you face any problems with names, I suggest you to rename everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version:

```
rsolve({a(0) = 1, a(1) = 2, a(n) = 2*a(n - 1) + 3*a(n - 2)}, a)
```