# Prove that infinite sequence defined recursively $a_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n+1}+a_{n})$ has limit and calculate it

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that infinite sequence defined recursively $a_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n+1}+a_{n})$ has limit and calculate it.
We know that $a_{1}=0 , a_{2}=1$.
I truly do not know how to proceed further. My teacher gave us a tip that we should separate it to even and odd partial series. But I wasn't able to get something useful from that.


Thanks for help:)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try to separate even and odd terms. You should use the theorem that states if you have an increasing/decreasing bounded sequence then the limit exists.

So, try to show that the odd and even sub-sequences of $\{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ form an/a increasing/decreasing sequence and see if you can show that they are bounded or not.

Comment: To calculate the limit, you should first solve the recurrence relation and find $a_n$ I think. This is usually covered in a course about discrete mathematics or linear algebra, I'm not sure if it's taught in analysis or calculus. But the existence of the limit can be shown that way.

Comment: $\{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is neither increasing or decreasing, but the odd / even partial series definitely are.

Comment: @chx: Yes, I meant the same thing. I'll fix it.

Comment: I already put that answer in :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it with Maple, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586646/how-to-define-a-recurrence-relation-in-maple/586670#586670) from me. You will first get an explicit form of that recurrence relation and then you can deduce the limit from it.

Answer (score 0):

The partial series are monotonic (one increasing, one decreasing) and bound. They have limits. Consider whether these limits can be different.